# Two Sub procedures, why does this function causes an object variable error after running through both once

Tags: vba, function, excel, scope

I have two Sub procedures both of which are too incredibly long to paste in here in their entirety, however I have narrowed the code block down to the following function and calling procedure which are causing the error.

I am able to run Sub 1 and Then Sub 2 without any problems, then when I try to rerun Sub 1 I receive an `object variable not set` error on this line which is in Sub 1:

```
        cName = "Current Price"
        cG = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
```

"Current Price" is spelled correctly and is a column header on each worksheet being passed as a parameter, and again Sub 1 runs fine the first time through, could this be an issue of public declaration? **The error is attributed to the `IsInArray` function below**

**Sub 1**

```
Sub Example(ws_string As String)

Sheets(ws_string).Activate

LR = Range("a1000").End(xlUp).Row
LC = Range("zz1").End(xlToLeft).Column


        cName = "Fund ID"
        cA = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        cName = "BBH ID"
        cB = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        cName = "Description"
        cC = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        cName = "Security Type"
        cD = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        cName = "Price Date"
        cF = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        cName = "Current Price"
        cG = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        cName = "Prior Price"
    cH = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
```

**Sub 2**

```
Set aSelection = Range("C2:C1500")
Set aSelect_Recon = Sheets("Recon").Range("L2:C1500")
For Each cell In aSelection
  If IsInRange(cell.Value, aSelect_Recon) Then
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

  End If
Next cell


Function IsInRange(stringToBeFound As String, ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = rng.Find(What:=stringToBeFound, _
        MatchCase:=True, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        Lookat:=xlPart) 'partial match to have the same behaviour as the filter version
    If Not r Is Nothing Then IsInRange = True
End Function
```

**EDIT UPDATE**
Further, I call Sub 1 three times passing a different worksheet as so:

```
Example "ETF"
Example "MAV"
Example "Main"
```

But if I comment out the ETF and MAV calls, the Main procedure call works fine.

Comment: Slight off topic; as a rule of thumb any sub or function that cannot fit on one screen is [too big](http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_subroutines.html).  Breaking your code into small specialized blocks, each of which has one - and only one - purpose, makes debugging a lot easier.  On the subject of debugging the [locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264148.aspx) window and hovering over the variables at run time should help you diagnose the fault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Set` find values, can't asign them

```
Set rngTest = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
if Not rngTest is Nothing then
    cA= rngTest.Column
end if
```

Suggestion: Start using `Option Explicit`, that will help alot to avoid these sort of errors.

Comment: But `.Column` makes it an integer/long so `Set` isn't necessary/right.

Comment: if nothing is found , Column will throw the error. So first set the range , check if its not nothing and then look for column. I didn't look till the end. See this issue is always because of no variable declration .:) Actually I was lazy too. :) Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem: The options of the `Find` method get saved. (They are the same as in the find window in excel).
After running the `IsInRange` function, the option `MatchCase` is set to `True`. In your example sub you have are looking for `UCase(cName)` so you are looking for `"CURRENT PRICE"` when you run it after `IsInRange` and it throws the `Object not set` error when it can't find it.

The solution would be to set `MatchCase:=False` in the `Example` sub.

edit: Follow cyboashu's advice about `Option Explicit` and checking the object first even if this solves the problem right now!

(PS: I included the `MatchCase:=True` option in the `IsInRange` function to reproduce the same result as the `Filter` function.)

**Also please accept an answer if it solved your problem** (you might even upvote it).

If it doesn't solve your problem, write a comment and explain why.

Comment: I set `MatchCase:=False` in the function and that did not solve the problem. I agree with your logic tho as I never had a problem with the `ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)` lines before adding this function

Comment: @phillipsK in your edit you say you encounter the problem without calling `IsInRange` as well so there seems to be another problem. Make absolutely sure that the sheet contains what you're looking for at the time you call the sub again. to Please try to make the problem reproducible by removing all code that doesn't cause the problem and posting the complete (remaining) sub.